# What are the things that you test in a controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Let say you have a register action in your controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Register(string username, string email, string password, string repeatPassword)
```

This action will:

1. Check and validate parameters
2. Communicate and add a new data to
   repository
3. Return a View.

Definitely need to unit test 1 and 3, but how about 2? 
Is there any way to unit test 2 without having to implement the add method in the repository?

Thanks,

RWendi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test for #2 using Moq would be:

```
[Test]
public void UserIsAddedToRepository()
{
    // arrange
    var username = "user1";
    var email = "email@address";
    var password = "password";
    var controller = new LoginController();
    var mockUserRepo = new Mock<IUserRepo>();
    mockUserRepo.Setup(m => m.AddNewUser(username, email, password));

    // act
    controller.Register(username, email, password, "");

    // assert
    mockUserRepo.Verify(m => m.AddNewUser(username, email, password));
}
```

Moq's *Verify* will behave like NUnit *Assert* and will fail the test if the expected method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test number 2, you can use mocking. You can mock your repository and return valid result for the test.

You can do the mock manually (in several ways, for example pass a parameter to the action method with the relevant repository - real or mock; or instantiate the controller class with the relevant mock object etc.) or you can use a mocking library like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Comment: Let say you mock your repository, and setup the repository add method to return a user object. How do you write your test, for the register action, to unit test number 2?